# Oracle Char type and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

I have a oracle table which contains char(n) type for several columns. I use hibernate tools to create entities objets and this tool map char type in String.

But when I deploy my application, I get an error because Hibernate wait a varchar2 type and not a char type:

```
Wrong column type in ARBOR.CMF for column CHG_WHO. Found: char, expected: varchar2(30 char)
```

What kind of java type must I use to map char(n) type in an entity ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's some useful information here [on this blog entry.](http://cedar715.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-wrong-column-type-found-char-expected-varchar2255/)

Essentially you need to make your hibernate configuration more specific, as it's assuming a default String mapping to varchar2(30).

You can try using the database-agnostic annotation of @Column(length=N) (where N is the actual length of your column in the database). If that doesn't work, try using the @Column(columnDefinition = "char") approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn't seen this property :)

Comment: I do not want to do this for each column. Is there any way that I can set some mapping for hibernate.

Comment: Don't copy/paste the columnDefinition field. Instead type it yourself ! I had some typo on the quotation marks.

Comment: My column datatype is `char`, so I have coded like below and it worked, Thanks stark! `@Column(name="ACTIVE_FLAG", length=1)
private String active;`

Answer (score 9):

Doesn't work - fails Hibernate schema validation:

```
@Column(name="ENABLED_FLAG", length=1)
private String enabledFlag;
```

Does work, since the `columnDefinition` attribute tells Hibernate not to default to `VARCHAR2` as the column type, and to use `CHAR` instead:

```
@Column(name="ENABLED_FLAG", length=1, columnDefinition="CHAR")
private String enabledFlag;
```

The column in the database is defined as:

```
ENABLED_FLAG CHAR(1 BYTE)
```