# Oracle char type issue in Hibernate HQL query

Tags: oracle, hibernate, types, char, hql

I have Oracle table, which contains char type columns. In my Entity class i mapped oracle char type to java string type.

Here is the code for my Entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORG")
public class Organization  {

private String serviceName;
private String orgAcct;

     //Some other properties goes here...

@Column(name="ORG_ACCT", nullable=false, length=16)
public String getOrgAcct() {
    return this.orgAcct;
}

public void setOrgAcct(String orgAcct) {
    this.orgAcct = orgAcct;
}


@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true, length=16)
public String getServiceName() {
    return this.serviceName;
}

public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
    this.serviceName = serviceName;
}

}
```

Here both serviceName and orgAcct are char type variables in Oracle

In my DAO class I wrote a HQL query to fetch Oranization entity object using serviceName and orgAcct properties.

```
@Repository
@Scope("singleton") //By default scope is singleton
public class OrganizationDAOImpl implementsOrganizationDAO {

public OrganizationDAOImpl(){
}

public Organization findOrganizationByOrgAcctAndServiceName(String orgAcct,String serviceName){
    String hqlQuery = "SELECT org FROM  Organization org WHERE org.serviceName = :serName AND org.orgAcct = :orgAct";
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hqlQuery)
        .setString("serName", serviceName)
        .setString("orgAct", orgAcct);

    Organization org =  findObject(query);
    return org;
}
 }
```

But when I call findOrganizationByOrgAcctAndServiceName() method , I am getting Organization object as null(i.e. HQL query is not retrieving Char type data ).

Please help me to fix this issue. Here I can't change Oracle type char to Varchar2. I need to work with oracle char type variables.

@EngineerDollery After going throw above post, I modified my Entity class with columnDefinition , `@Column` annotation attribute.

```
@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true,length=16,columnDefinition="CHAR")
    public String getServiceName() {
        return this.serviceName;
    }
```

But still I am not able to retrieve the data for corresponding columns.

and I added column size as well in columnDefinition attribute.

`@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true,length=16,columnDefinition="CHAR(16)`

But still same issue I am facing. 
Any thing Am I doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: When you run SQL manually from SQL Client against database, do you see any rows returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529897/oracle-char-type-and-hibernate

Comment: @EngineerDollery After going throw above post, I modified my Entity class with columnDefinition , column annoation attribute.

`@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true,length=16,columnDefinition="CHAR")
 public String getServiceName() {
  return this.serviceName;
 }
`

But still I am not able to retrieve the data for corresponding columns.

and I added column size as well in columnDefinition attribute.

`@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true,length=16,columnDefinition="CHAR(16)`

But still same issue I am facing. 
Any thing Am I doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Using `char` is almost always the wrong choice. Given the problems you have I'm pretty sure you actually want to use `varchar`. `char` is always **padded** to the defined length when storing the data. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't alter type of serviceName from char to varchar2. Because the same data base is using by other APIs (which were coded in C++). Can we have generic solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem using OraclePreparedStatement and Hibernate UserType interface.

Crated a new UserType class by extending org.hibernate.usertype.UserType interface and provided implementation for nullSafeSet(), nullSafeGet() methods .

nullSafeSet() method, we have first parameter as PreparedStatement, inside the method I casted  PreparedStatement into OraclePreparedStatement object and pass String value using setFixedCHAR() method.

Here is the complete code of UserType impl class.

```
package nc3.jws.persistence.userType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

/**
* 
* based on www.hibernate.org/388.html
*/

 public class OracleFixedLengthCharType implements UserType {

public OracleFixedLengthCharType() {
    System.out.println("OracleFixedLengthCharType constructor");
}

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.CHAR };
}



public Class<String> returnedClass() {
    return String.class;
}

public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
    return (x == y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.equals(y)));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet inResultSet, String[] names, Object o) throws SQLException {
    //String val = (String) Hibernate.STRING.nullSafeGet(inResultSet, names[0]);
    String val = StringType.INSTANCE.nullSafeGet(inResultSet, names[0]);
    //System.out.println("From nullSafeGet method valu is "+val);
    return val == null ? null : StringUtils.trim(val);
}


public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement inPreparedStatement, Object o,
        int i)
                throws SQLException {

    String val = (String) o;
    //Get the delegatingStmt object from DBCP connection pool PreparedStatement object.
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement delgatingStmt = (org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement)inPreparedStatement;
    //Get OraclePreparedStatement object using deletatingStatement object.

    oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement oraclePreparedStmpt = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement)delgatingStmt.getInnermostDelegate();
    //Call setFixedCHAR method, by passing string type value .
    oraclePreparedStmpt.setFixedCHAR(i, val);
}


public Object deepCopy(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new String(((String) o));
}


public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
}

public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) {
    return cached;
}


public Serializable disassemble(Object value) {
    return (Serializable) value;
}

public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) {
    return original;
}

public int hashCode(Object obj) {
    return obj.hashCode();
}

  }
```

Configured this class with @TypeDefs annotation in Entity class.

```
@TypeDefs({
@TypeDef(name = "fixedLengthChar", typeClass = nc3.jws.persistence.userType.OracleFixedLengthCharType.class)
```

})

Added this type to CHAR type columns

```
@Type(type="fixedLengthChar")
@Column(name="SERVICE_NAME",nullable=true,length=16)
public String getServiceName() {
    return this.serviceName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

char types are padded with spaces in the table. This means that if you have

```
foo
```

in one of these columns, what you actually have is

```
foo<space><space><space>...
```

until the actual length of the string is 16.

Consequently, if you're looking for an organization having `"foo"` as its service name, you won't find any, because the actual value in the table if `foo` padded with 13 spaces.

You'll thus have to make sure all your query parameters are also padded with spaces.

Comment: I can't predict serviceName value at run time, how can i append spaces to serviceName<<=16) .. I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: You use a loop to append spaces until the length of the string is 16.