# Oracle CHAR column and trailing spaces with JDBC

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, datasource

I've been reading some posts about this problem but I can't find a solution for my environment.

I'm using Oracle Driver 11.2.0.3.0 and Spring JDBC 4.1.4.RELEASE.

From this [site](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html) I get that Oracle by default uses VARCHAR semantics with String arguments, which produces the error I'm dealing with (if I compare 'a' with 'a    ' it doesn't match).

In theory using the connection parameter "fixedString=true" it should fix the problem. However using it in my [datasource configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) it doesn't make any change.

```
<bean id="dataSourcePool" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="connectionProperties" value="fixedString=true;" />
</bean>
```

I tried using the OracleDataSource instead of commons, just in case, but it didn't work.

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I found a workaround, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it works without the parameter "fixedString".

Before I was setting my SQL parameters in Spring JDBC like this (it's an example):

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("newCharParemeter", "hello");
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, new MyMapper());
```

Debugging the class `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, we found that Spring is calling the method `PreparedStatement.setString` because it doesn't know what type of parameter is "newCharParameter".

If I modify the previous code to:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("newCharParemeter", new SqlParameterValue(OracleTypes.FIXED_CHAR, "hello"));
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, new MyMapper());
```

Then everything works as expected becase Spring calls to `PreparedStatement.setObject` removing trailing blanks thanks to the type `FIXED_CHAR`.

Comment: See if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24016521/1126526) helps.  I have a [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-oracle) that contains the necessary code mentioned in this post.

Comment: I checked your post but there they use Hibernate, we use Spring JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<property name="connectionProperties" value="fixedString='true';" />
```

or

```
<property name="connectionProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="fixedString">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

But probably the best option is to convert all CHAR columns to VARCHAR in database. If you use in oracle eg. CHAR(2) you have to insert there 2 chars, compare with 2 chars etc.

Comment: I've been debugging the class BasicDataSource, setConnectionProperties is summoned properly and the parameter is setted. Converting CHAR to VARCHAR is not an option. I think that the problem might be in JdbcTemplate, ignoring the parameter `fixedString`.

Comment: Check if parameter is string "true" not boolean true

Comment: It doesn't matter, the method setConnectionProperties uses the method [Properties.setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with String parameters.