Hibernate session.get for String to Oracle CHAR query fails due to padding
We've Oracle DB which stores the data column using CHAR data type. Hibernate entity of the same has been mapped to java.lang.String.
Java 8
Hibernate 5.6.15
Oracle Database 19c
DB
"ACCOUNT_NO" CHAR(16 CHAR)
Hibernate Entity Class
public class AcctId  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String accountNo;
    
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO", length=16)
    public String getAccountNo() {
        return this.accountNo;
    }
    
    public void setAccountNo(String accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }
     
}

When we do hibernate session.get on this accountNo of length 16 CHAR, we are able to get the account as expected. But, when the accountNo is less than 16 hibernate session.get is not returning any rows even though the account exists.
I understand this is due to the Oracle padding the account with extra spaces when the length of account is less than 16 char. As the data type in Oracle is CHAR.
Also, we cannot alter the database columns to varchar2. I've roughly about 100 hibernate entities similar to this. So padding would be tedious job. I'm looking for ways to fix this in hibernate.
I also have looked at some of the tech forums and tried the below. Unfortunately, they both are not working for me.
Solution 1: @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO", length=16, columnDefinition="CHAR")
Solution 2: Implemented userType like below:
    public class TrimmedStringType implements UserType {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.CHAR };

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        if (obj == null) {
        return null;
        }
        return new String((String) obj);
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return (x == y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.equals(y)));
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String val = rs.getString(names[0]);
        return val != null ? val.trim() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setString(index, (String)value);
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object obj) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String val = rs.getString(names[0]);
        return val != null ? val.trim() : null;
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement pstmt, Object obj, int i) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        pstmt.setString(i, (String)obj);
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
    }



Appreciate some help here.
Tried the solutions as mentioned in the description.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3529897/1509264

Solution recommended has already been tried and didn't work for columnDefinition.

Just because the answers to that question do not solve it for you does not mean that the questions are not fundamentally the same; if this was closed as a duplicate then you could still seek answers by, for example, putting a bounty on the other question.

That question doesn't deal with padding though, and not sure making it about that would be right. Maybe look at others like this or this?
